# Laravel 5.5 Validate multiple file upload

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.5

How do I validate multiple file uploads using only one validation on laravel?

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'project'           => 'required|exists:project_details,id',
    'location'          => 'exists:project_details,location',
    'plant_id'          => 'exists:project_details,plant_id',
    'capacity'          => 'required|max:20',
    'brief_description' => 'nullable|max:300',
    'incident_details'  => 'required|max:300',
    'other_comments'    => 'nullable|max:300',
    'attachments.*'     => 'required|file|mimes:xlsx,xls,csv,jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,doc,docx,pdf,tif,tiff'
]);
```

I'm trying to validate the attachments.
Here's my form:

```
<input type="file" name="attachments[]" multiple>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You can validate your file following way.**

```
$input_data = $request->all();

$validator = Validator::make(
$input_data, [
'image_file.*' => 'required|file|mimes:xlsx,xls,csv,jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,doc,docx,pdf,tif,tiff'
],[
    'image_file.*.required' => 'Please upload an image',
    'image_file.*.mimes' => 'Only xlsx,xls,csv,jpg,jpeg,png,bmp,doc,docx,pdf,tif,tiff images are allowed',

]
);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Your erorr message');
}
```

Comment: @RalphVitto. I can understand your problem. I will add a solution to this issue. Please check my answer.

Comment: @RalphVitto you can simple call the validate() method at the end of validate:make()->validate();